# Creating shopping basket using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a shopping basket with PHP, I want to pass through a bunch of IDS and query the database for them. At the moment I recieve this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(1\', \'10\', \'6\', \'23)'' at line 1

Here is the function I am using

```
function find_item_db($product_code) {
try{
$query = substr($product_code, 0,-1);
$product_codes = explode(",", $query);
$ids = '';
foreach($product_codes as $code) {
$params[] = $code;
$ids .= '?, ';
} 
$ids = '(' . rtrim($ids, ', ') . ')';
//we need to get product name and price from database.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Sweets` WHERE `Sweet_ID` IN $ids";
$statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($params);
return $result = $statement->fetchAll();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage(). "<br/>";
}    

}
```

Can anyone see where I am getting a syntax error here?

Comment: Looks like you might have magic_quotes enabled, is that the case? The quotes are being escaped from what I see in the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have each value have its own placeholder. Try:

```
$product_codes = explode(",", $query);
$ids = '';
foreach($product_codes as $code) {
    $params[] = $code;
    $ids .= '?, ';
} 
$ids = '(' . rtrim($ids, ', ') . ')';
//we need to get product name and price from database.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Sweets` WHERE `Sweet_ID` IN $ids";
$statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($params);
```

Note `$ids` is just a list of placeholders, the actual values are bound in the `execute`.

Rough demo of how it works: https://eval.in/520334

Comment: You're one step closer to writing your own ORM at this point. There's a number of very good ones out there that are worth considering if you need more than the very basic functionality PDO provides.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you, this now works. However I am now getting duplicates of the result. So 2 of everything...?

Comment: @AlexAnderson you are still using the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and getting duplicates, or is it an associative and indexed return?

Comment: @chris85 I am using fetchALL. I have edited my code above to show you what I am now using.

Comment: You are getting both associative and indexed array. Try to use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, or specify what type you want returned. It defaults to both. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php `which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH`.